# Is it possible to inherit base class from shared module in Angular without explicit import

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-modules, angular15

In my project there are many "base" component classes. Furthermore, the project is to be divided into several other modules, in which I simply wanted to use the share module as a base classes source.

I hoped that it would be possible to use just one simple `import { SharedModule }` declaration in `app.module` and avoid many imports of base component classes in component descendants, but error occured.

(I've edited this question to be more precise.)

Example:

```
// base.component.ts
@Component({ selector: 'app-base', ...})
export class BaseComponent {}
```

```
// shared.module.ts
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BaseComponent } from './base/base.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [BaseComponent],
  exports: [BaseComponent],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

```
// app.module.ts
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [..., SharedModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I know that this works (but is not my intended use):

```
// hello.component.ts
@Component({ template: `<app-base></app-base>` })
export class HelloComponent {}
```

I thought it would work too, but it doesn't:

```
// hello.component.ts
@Component({...})
export class HelloComponent extends BaseComponent {} // <-- Cannot find name 'BaseComponent'
```

Does angular allow using the base class in the above simple way somehow? (i.e. without `import { BaseComponent }` in each component descendant)

Comment: Try following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-component-inheritance) tutorial

Answer (score 2):

First of all, using a sharedModule is often an old bad practice, better to use SCAM (Single Component Angular Module) or Standalone Components.

Anyway, if you want to extend BaseComponent, you can do it, but you have to import it  `import { BaseComponent } from './base/base.component';`
if you don't intend to use the BaseComponent itself, there is no need to declare it in any module, you just need to declare the HomeComponent

Comment: Why it is a bad practice to use a shared Module?

Comment: basically if you have a big shared module, lazy-loading won't work as intended, and you end up with a big bundle size. The app can't be tree-shaken if you have a big Shared Module.
As mentioned the SCAM architecture or Standalone Components are preferred.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you have any links, articles about this?

Comment: you will find many if you google, but here is one about shared material module: https://indepth.dev/posts/1191/stop-using-shared-material-module

Answer (score 1):

View [this](https://medium.com/@nishantisme/using-component-from-a-shared-module-in-angular-70a77866653f) complete tutorial.

Use the component from the shared module as a base class in your child component:

In the “child.component.ts” file, extend the base component using the extends keyword:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseComponent } from '../shared/base/base.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello',
  template: `
    <app-base></app-base>
    <p>Hello Component works!</p>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent  extends BaseComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Make sure that you are using the selector of the parent component in the appropriate template file.

Use the hello component anywhere in your template:
In the template where you want to use the hello component, include the hello component using its selector:

```
<app-hello></app-hello>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - so if I understand correctly, without "manually" importing `base.component` it is not possible to inherit component

Comment: @user4662448 you understood correctly, kindly upvote and mark it as correct answer if it helped you.